# Core Data data encryption

Tags: ios, core-data

From what I understand, to enable data encryption for Core Data the device needed to enable/turn on Passcode and included this key in the optional dictionary for the `addPersistentStoreWithType`: method.  I did enable Passcode for my device and this code in the project:

```
NSPersistentStore *store = [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                   configuration:nil
                                                                             URL:self.storeURL
                                                                         options:@{ NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"iCloudStore",
                                                                                    NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey : NSFileProtectionComplete}
                                                                           error:&error];
```

But when I opened the sqlite data file directly using a software called Liya (downloaded from Mac app store), I was able to see the data in the sqlite database.   I saved the sqlite database file from my device to my Mac using iTunes filesharing.

Since data were encrypted, should I not be able to see data directly using tools such as Liya at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encryption only works on the device. Files you copy off the device via iTunes or Xcode always get decrypted. When you pair your device with iTunes it creates a copy of all the encryption keys from the phone on your computer. That is necessary so iTunes can create backups and sync while your phone is locked.