# iOS Encrypting Core Data database

Tags: encryption, core-data, encrypted-core-data-sql

I have a Core Data database with a lot of sensitive information, so I like to encrypt it.

Almost all information about encrypting Core Data databases seem to be quite outdated:

- Creating the persistent store coordinator with `NSFileProtectionComplete`.
  But copying the files off the device with iTunes or Xcode decrypts the database (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823240/8837882). And the database seems to get decrypted as soon as device is unlocked, no matter if the app is running or not.
- Encrypting database with https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data. The last commit is from 2017.

So I'd like to ask if this recommendations are still up to date or if there are better ones at the end of 2020?

Comment: Did you try the GitHub project? Does it not work?

Comment: That's actually part of my question: The latest commit dates back to 2017 (the latest release to 2016). So is it still reliable or should no longer be used e.g. due to known vulnerabilities? And any other recommendations to encrypt the Core Data database?